# How to get ethernet in Ubuntu 14 / Virtualbox 5.0.20 / Windows 7 to work

Tags: 14.04, networking, virtualbox

To start my latest and greatest programming project... I updated VirtualBox to 5.0.20 (because the nag splash is very annoying).

Then I downloaded a fresh 14.04 from osboxes.org
Then, I ran it and I had plenty of networking.
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
Install Virtual box guest additions
Reboot...

And now the wired ethernet in Ubuntu 14.04 is not working.

Even more strangely... Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 15.04 of other VM's still work  and get on internet even after shutdown/boot.

I did try changing my Network adapter "attached to:" to "NAT" and made sure the virtualbox bridge was loaded.
(as suggested here
[Internet isn't working in Ubuntu 14.04 as VirtualBox Guest OS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487114/internet-isnt-working-in-ubuntu-14-04-as-virtualbox-guest-os))

So I am a little stumped on what to try next to troubleshoot this problem.

[EDIT] The best I can figure is that the latest Guest additions for 5.0.20, which are NOT installed in the other VMs, are to blame.  If that's true... would I try to install an old version and overwrite?  And where to get the old version?

Comment: when you say the wired ethernet is not working, what does this mean ? You can not see the interface listed under ifconfig or you are not getting the IP Address assigned to the interfaces ? can you please clarify?

Comment: It says the adapter is "disconnected."

Comment: I get messages on boot up "adapter is disconnected" - I can use the "wireless connectivity" icon in top right to see the status is disconnected.

Comment: The adapater shows up in ifconfig, showing 0 packets, and no IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

Something was corrupted.  I started over and unziped a new VM .vdi copy

It works now